# How to save Array of NSDictionary items in separate array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, alamofire

My json data sample is

```
[
{
 "id": "244",
 "name": "PIZZAS",
 "image": "",
 "coupon": "1",
 "icon": "",
 "order": "1",
 "aname": "",
 "options": "2",
 "subcategory": [
                  {
                    "id": "515",
                    "name": "MARGARITA",
                    "description": "Cheese and Tomato",
                    "image": "",
                    "icon": "",
                    "coupon": "1",
                    "order": "1",
                    "aname": "",
                    "options": "2",
                    "item": [
                                {
                                   "id": "1749",
                                   "name": "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita",
                                   "description": "",
                                   "price": "3.40",
                                   "coupon": "1",
                                   "image": "",
                                   "options": "2",
                                   "order": "1",
                                   "addon": "495",
                                   "aname": "",
                                   "icon": ""
                            }]
              }]
}]
```

This Json is not the whole data. I simply gave the sample data like that.Because not possible to sent all data.
I can able to get the response data in Array of NSdDictionary each particular items. After that I am trying to save each particular data like all names, all subcategory names, all items name in an array so that i can display it in table view . I have used the following codes

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl, parameters:nil , encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON
        { response in
            // print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")


            let array = response.result.value as! Array<NSDictionary>
            for item in array
            {
                let Name = item["name"]!
                print(Name)
                self.menuName.arrayByAddingObject(Name)  ///error below mentioned
                let ID = item["id"]!
                print(ID)
                let Order = item["order"]!
                print(Order)
                let Subcategories = item["subcategory"]! as! Array<NSDictionary>
                //print(Subcategories)
                for subCategory in Subcategories
                {
                    let subId = subCategory["id"]!
                     print(subId)
                    let subName = subCategory["name"]!
                     print(subName)

                    let subDesc = subCategory["description"]!
                    print(subDesc)
                    let suborder = subCategory["order"]!
                    print(suborder)
                    let SubItems = subCategory["item"]! as! Array<NSDictionary>
                    //print(SubItems)
                    for subItem in SubItems
                    {
                        let itemId = subItem["id"]!
                        print(itemId)
                        let itemName = subItem["name"]!
                        print(itemName)

                        let itemPrice = subItem["price"]!
                        print(itemPrice)
                        let itemOrder = subItem["order"]!
                         print(itemOrder)
                        let itemAddOn = subItem["addon"]!
                        print(itemAddOn)
                    }
                }

            }
             print("Names of menu are : \(menuName)")
```

I have taken the menuName as `NSArray`. the Error came `"can't unwrap the optional value "`. how to implement this??

Comment: why not use SwiftyJSON? It is very compatible with Alamofire

Comment: I am already implement Alamofire so far. So if you any idea in it let me know@AkshanshThakur

Comment: SwiftyJSON is a library that you can use to parse JSON very nicely without all these complications and type checks. link : https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: ok i tried to add the pod file and install the pod file but it takes so much time .Also i tried to add it manually. like directly add the swiftJson.swift file. but after that so many errors came. so I removed it@AkshanshThakur

Comment: Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.  this error came@AkshanshThakur

Comment: Add this to your podFile : 
`pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'`

And do pod install

Comment: I have manually added swiftJson.xcodeproj inside my project under my project name in Xcode and set the framework into the project. Now my project able to import the swiftyjson@AkshanshThakur